# jQuery condition if input selected and button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following input list:

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500' value='182,500'> Below QAR 182,500 <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500plus' value='182,500plus'> Above QAR 182,500 – Below QAR 365,000 <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='365,000' value='365,000'> Above QAR 365,000

<span class="custom-link btn border-width-0 info-submit btn-color-xsdn btn-outline btn-icon-left">Submit</span>
```

I want to create an if statement where if the `input` with the `name` attribute `182,500` is checked and if the `span` with the class `.info-submit` is clicked, a snippet of code is executed.

Maybe something like that:

```
if ($("input[name = '182,500']").attr('checked') && $(".section-2-1 .info-submit").click() ) {
  // execute code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on('click')` method you can check if the `input` is checked or not using `prop`

```js
$('.info-submit').on('click', function() {
  $('[name="182,500"]').prop('checked') ? 
    console.log('clicked and checked') : 
    console.log('clicked only')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500' value='182,500'> Below QAR 182,500 <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500plus' value='182,500plus'> Above QAR 182,500 – Below QAR 365,000 <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='365,000' value='365,000'> Above QAR 365,000
<br />
<span class="custom-link btn border-width-0 info-submit btn-color-xsdn btn-outline btn-icon-left">Submit</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is check that the input with the required name is checked when the `info-submit` button is clicked. For this case, you can use `.is(':checked')` on the input. It will give you true or false depending on it's state.

```
$('.info-submit').on('click', function() {
    // This will check if the input is checked or not.
    if($("input[name='182,500']").is(':checked')) {
        // Do something.
    }
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `name='182.500'` doesn't exist.

Comment: Since when name='value' doesn't exist? Been using it for a long time now.

Comment: @AlainCruz you used a dot not comma in the value

Comment: Ohhh, didn't see that. I get it. Changed 182.500 for 182,500.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.info-submit').on('click', function () {
    // This will check if the input is checked or not.
    if ($("input[name='182.500']").prop('checked')) {
        // Do something.
    }
})
```

Comment: You are setting the attribute and your `if` will always be truthy. Use `prop()` for boolean

Comment: I forgot...sorry